# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' for Google E-books

Tags: php, google-api, google-books

In PHP, I am trying to access google e-books through google api but i am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Henry+David+Thoreau&filter=free-ebooks&key=AIzaSyCc5s6WLKl9SrvlsN-8yXO6Cmd4qeAYR08:
>   (403) Insufficient Permission' in
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php(593):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Go in
>   /home/stealthbeta/public_html/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 110

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("XXXXXX");
$client->setClientId("XXXXXXX");
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('XXXXX');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books'));

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
     }
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
    $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
    $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

    foreach ($results as $item) {
        echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: please add some code to your Question.  We already tide with reading error !!